# Overwrite NHibernate classmapping with FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We have a developed a new product based on a legacy database.

We use NHibernate for our DAL and FluentNHibernate for mapping.

The developed product is mostly standard software, however we have one customer which uses a slightly different database for its backend.

Now, we already have an infrastructure in place to load specific modules dynamically.

Our idea was to overwrite several entity mappings in such a module. However, we can't find a way to overwrite the NHibernate classmappings.

What would be the best approach to overriding an already mapped class using (fluent) NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate the mappings and then load the assemblies dynamically.

Comment: Yes that is an option, but it requires more work and does not fit into our infrastructure that well.